# Set HTML style value for CheckBox

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

I am generating a checkbox and I want to set the style property to `display:none`,
how can I do that?

Here is the HTML Helper that I am using to create the checkbox control

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => allProviders[i].Selected, new { value = allProviders[i].ProviderCode, id = allProviders[i].ProviderCode })
```

Comment: What is the point of a hidden checkbox - you may as well use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => allProviders[i].Selected)` And never try to set the `value` attribute (and the `id` is already created for you) - your `new { value = allProviders[i].ProviderCode, id = allProviders[i].ProviderCode }` is pointless since they are setting both attributes to what they already are.

Comment: Actually Later I will display only few of those checkboxes that would be matched to a condition in jquery. This is why

Comment: Just realized you binding to `Selected` but setting the value to `ProviderCode` which means it's not only pointless, its plain wrong! What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: Can we not add style to HTML Helpers?

Comment: Yes. `new { style = "display:none" }` or `new { @class = "yourClass" }` and use css. But the code you have shown cannot possibly work unless `ProviderCode` is also a `bool` (and then it would make no sense)